# Does a helmet become useless after it slips from the hand and hits the ground?

Tags: helmets

I have a STUDDS motorbike helmet purchased 10 years back which I wear even today. I have not met even one single accident, but several times due to my carelessness the helmet has fallen off my hands and landed on ground with a thud!

Now, I wish to know whether after a slip from the hand should a helmet be replaced?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about motorbikes, not bicycles.

Comment: Are the helmets too different for cycles and motorbikes? @DavidRicherby

Comment: Yes, they're very different in construction and the impacts they are designed to absorb. Many people would answer the same for both, but an answer based on one and backed up with data would not be valid for the other. The fact that a motorbike helmet is so much heavier means it has to absorb much more energy when dropped, for example

Comment: Motorcycle helmets certainly look different to bicycle helmets! We have no expertise in motorcycle helmets so we can't give you advice about them.

Comment: I would use it.

Comment: @DavidRicherby thanks for responding. Is there a site where I can ask this?

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl As far as I know, there are no Stack Exchange sites that cover motorcycling. [mechanics.se] covers motorcycle maintenance as well as cars, but this isn't a maintenance question so it's off-topic there. Unfortunately, you'll have to find a site outside Stack Exchange. You could also visit [area51.se] and try to start a motorcycling site.

Comment: @DavidRicherby can the physics site cover this?

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl I doubt it. You're not asking about physical principles but about the safety of a specific object.

Comment: @DavidRicherby how would you be able to answer such question when OP will ask about bicycle helmet? Even if there is no noticeable cracks or damages the shell may be weakened and perform worse during accident. To tell if it is safe or not it should be thoroughly examined, including radiograph, I guess. Everything less is just an irresponsible speculation.

Comment: @krzyski This question is objectively off-topic because it is not about bicycles. This isn't the place to discuss whether other hypothetical questions should be closed.

Comment: @DavidRicherby so the comment above should be "We don't answer motorcycle question because it's bicycle site" rather than "We have no expertise in motorcycle helmets so we can't give you advice". Second suggests that "expertise in bicycle helmets" authorizes online bicycle helmets inspection. It doesn't.

Comment: @krzyski Fine. Whatever. The question is off-topic. Can't that be the end of it?

Comment: @DavidRicherby Sure, as you wish. I put safety-connected advice over stackexchange overscrupulousness, especially when the answer is the same for both bicycle- and not-bicycle case: "take it to your dealer to be inspected by a trained professional".

Comment: shouldnt you get a new helmet after 10 years anyway??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering your general question:

PROBABLY not, according to [Snell Foundation](http://www.smf.org/helmetfaq#aDroppedHelmet):

> **"I dropped my helmet! Do I have to go buy a new one?"**
>
> Generally the answer is probably not.  Helmets are one-use items, but are quite durable otherwise, at least the ones we certify. Frequent dropping or spiking   a helmet on the ground, or other hard surfaces may eventually degrade the helmet's performance.  Similarly if the helmet falls to the ground at highway speeds unoccupied, the owner must be aware that some degradation may have occurred.   In general, the real damage comes when the helmet contacts an object with a head inside.  The Foundation recommends that if you are participating in an activity that requires that you wear a helmet, you avoid hitting stuff with your head.  **It can be difficult to readily determine if a helmet has been damaged**, and the protective capabilities compromised without a thorough **inspection by a trained professional**.  Some manufacturers may provide this service or direct you to these others that can perform these inspections.  The Foundation recommends that if you suspect your helmet may be compromised, then replace it. If the helmet has been involved in an impact while in use, replace it.

But for your actual helmet you should have not any doubts - **throw it away**. As for motorcycle helmet it is [**very** old](http://www.smf.org/helmetfaq#aWhyReplace). Even when new, your helmet presented worse performance than contemporary mid-end products.

Note for off-topic voters:
It **is** off-topic.

but

It is **very important** safety issue.

Comment: `Even when new, your helmet presented worse performance than contemporary mid-end products.` Why did you say this?

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl I'm inferring from statistics: https://crashstats.nhtsa.dot.gov/Api/Public/ViewPublication/809715